# ESP32-S3: High (>500µA) deep sleep current with peripherals and GPIOs isolated

Tags: esp32

I'm debugging an ESP32-S3 module at the moment with a very high deep sleep current. That device is not running much more than a Bluedroid BLE GATT server and is built onto a custom PCB. I've isolated all other power consumers on the board, so the ESP is the only thing running.

I've attempted to isolate GPIOs and have tried manually disabling the BT controller before entering deep sleep. Interestingly, when I run `esp_bt_controller_disable()` it increases the deep sleep current to 1.8mA. If that command isn't run, the chip consumes 500µA when in a deep sleep, which is far from the <10µA I'm expecting.

The chip is not running the ESP ADC but has SPI peripherals and GPIOs. Here's an abbreviated version of the sleep function:

```c
void power_modes_sleep(void) {
    /* Initialize selected GPIOs as RTC IO, enable input, disable pullup and pulldown */

    /* Load ULP program and start the ULP. */
    esp_err_t err = ulp_riscv_load_binary(ulp_main_bin_start, (ulp_main_bin_end - ulp_main_bin_start));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(err);

    /* Start the ULP program. */
    err = ulp_riscv_run();
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(err);

    rtc_gpio_isolate(GPIO_NUM_1);
    ...
    rtc_gpio_isolate(GPIO_NUM_20);

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_bt_controller_disable());
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_sleep_enable_ulp_wakeup());

    /* Go back to sleep, only the ULP Risc-V will run. */
    printf("Entering to deep sleep in 0..\n\n");

    /* Small delay to ensure the messages are printed. */
    vTaskDelay(100);

    /* Turn off main processor. */
    esp_deep_sleep_start();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The code comment says this function disables pull up and pull downs, can you physically disconnect the GPIO so you know that those aren't leaking?  Or I guess you could turn them on/off one at a time to verify the current changes.

Comment: It's soldered onto a PCB, so it's challenging to disconnect one at a time, but I suspect something has got to be leaking at this point. I'm hoping it's not electrical but configurable by setting pin state but given I feel like I'm isolating all GPIOs I'm not sure that's tenable